# Generating a token for API Authentication with Python

Tags: javascript, python, jwt, token

I'm trying create an API application using Python. 
In order to access this API, the app must generate a token 
that has the format: `<key>:<hash>:<epoch>`

The [docs for the API](https://uat1.adstreamdev.com/api/v2/docs/#/guides/authentication.md) use javascript for an example of how to generate the token.

> You can generate the hash from your key and secret in the following
>   way;
>
> `var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(key +`
>   `epoch).digest('base64');`
>
> ```
> 1- Create sha256 hash from secret.
> 2- Update with key and epoch concatenated.
> 3- Return base64 representation.
> ```
>
> The application token can then be added to the 'Authorization' header
>   as follows;
>
> `Authorization: A5-API <token>`

Seems pretty straightforward, but my python code is resulting in a 401 error.

```
{'status': 401, 'name': 'NotAuthorizedError', 'message': 'You must use a valid A5 Authorisation token'}
```

Seems like somehow I'm generating an invalid token, but I've been through it a dozen times and 
don't see what could be wrong.

I know this is not an issue of a bad key/secret, because when I test with the key/secret 
on the api dev website, the token is generated just fine.

So I'm wondering if anyone can notice something potentially wrong with the code I'm using?

thanks!

Please see my code below (API key, secret, and url removed).

```
import base64
import hashlib
import requests
import time
import urllib.parse

"""
auth-token example: 
A5-API 5eb77cd86erb50010f57c2ce:gUrQbsIV+S9Fyq8yIzAS+cl2Q3zizQLrFMDGq7zubaI=:1590105400
"""

key = <key>
secret = <secret>
epoch = str(time.mktime(time.localtime()))[:-2]

h = hashlib.sha256(secret.encode())
h_update = (key + epoch).encode('utf-8')
h.update(h_update)
hash_encode = base64.b64encode(h.digest())
hash_decode = hash_encode.decode('utf-8')
epoch = str(time.mktime(time.localtime()))[:-2]
token = f"{key}:{hash_decode}:{epoch}"
authorization =  f"A5-API {token}"

headers = {"Authorization": authorization }

url = <api url>

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

Comment: `The docs for the API use javascript for an example of how to generate the token.` <- Can you please give a link to the docs.

Comment: sure. here's the [link](https://uat1.adstreamdev.com/api/v2/docs/#/guides/authentication.md)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
url='xxxx'
secret='xxxxx'
key='xxxxx' 
epoch = str(time.mktime(time.localtime()))[:-2]

message = key + epoch
hash_object = hmac.new(secret.encode("utf-8"), message.encode("utf-8"), 
hashlib.sha256)
hash = base64.b64encode(hash_object.digest()).decode("utf-8")
token = f"{key}:{hash}:{epoch}"
authorization =  f"A5-API {token}"

headers = {"Authorization": authorization }

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).